# O que significa os dois pontos aqui?

Tags: javascript, sequelize-js

Na documentação do sequelize tem essa linha de código.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:')
```

Oque significa os dois pontos dublo e os dois pontos sozinho no final

Comment: O `:memory:`  é uma sintaxe do próprio SQLite, como pode ver na documentação: https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html, não é do Sequelize-js e não são os dois pontos finais, o que vem depois do `sqlite:` poderá também ser arquivo, em resumo, para o [tag:sequelize-js] é algo como `<tipo do banco>:<instruções>`

Comment: Em especial, do link que foi passado anteriormente, note o trecho _The special ":memory:" filename also works when using URI filenames. For example:_  `c = sqlite3_open("file::memory:", &db);` - ou seja, isso é o URI scheme do SQLite mesmo, onde `sqlite:` é um prefixo, e `:memory:` se refere ao DB em memória. Resta ver se o sequelize tem algum tratamento especial para o prefixo, para escolher o engine, o que faria sentido se é multi-db.

Answer (score -3):

A linha de código que você mencionou cria uma instância do Sequelize, uma biblioteca de ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) para Node.js, e configura-a para usar um banco de dados SQLite em memória.

A parte 'sqlite::memory:' da linha de código representa a string de conexão para o banco de dados SQLite em memória.

Aqui está a explicação:

1. 'sqlite:': Indica o tipo de banco de dados que o Sequelize deve
   usar, que é SQLite neste caso. ':memory:':
2. Especifica que o banco de dados SQLite deve ser criado na memória do
   sistema em vez de ser um     arquivo em disco. Ou seja, ':memory:'
   instrui o SQLite a criar um     banco de dados que existe apenas
   enquanto o programa estiver em execução e será descartado quando o
   programa terminar. na verdade o banco de dados criado com :memory: deixa de existir assim que a conexão com o banco de dados é encerrada ou seja os dados em memória podem ser descartados antes da aplicação terminar caso a conexão com o banco de dados seja interrompida implicando na perda irrecuperável de informações causada por motivos externos e não controlados pela aplicação.

Portanto, a linha de código cria uma instância do Sequelize e a configura para usar um banco de dados SQLite temporário na memória.

Comment: O item 2 não está correto. O nome especial de arquivo `:memory:` realmente cria um banco de dados residente unicamente na memória mas não existe garantias de que seu ciclo de vida seja coincidente ao ciclo de vida da aplicação, na verdade *o banco de dados criado com `:memory:` deixa de existir assim que a conexão com o banco de dados é encerrada* ou seja os dados em memória podem ser descartados antes da aplicação terminar caso a conexão com o banco de dados seja interrompida implicando na perda irrecuperável de informações causada por motivos externos e não controlados pela aplicação.

Comment: *".... se a conexão com banco é fechada é o mesmo que a aplicação ter sido encerrada do ponto de vista do banco de dados....."*, ***NÃO** diversos fatores externos e independentes da aplicação podem fechar conexões locais de banco de dados locais antes da aplicação principal ser fechada, como condições de corrida e deadlocks, mal gerenciamento de memória de memória, leitura/escrita simultânea em banco de dados corrompidos, freeze timeout, politicas administrativas, falha de hardware...... são muitas as possibilidades da conexão mesmo que local ser interrompida e o usuário tem que estar ciente.

Comment: Não consigo entender o que leva alguém que tem todas as ferramentas e mecanismos - bastando gastar uns 40 segundos para aprimorar a postagem - preferir justificar existência de conteúdo que pode induzir a erro. Então fica o **aviso ao leitor**: A frase _"existe apenas enquanto o programa estiver em execução e será descartado quando o programa terminar."_ não é absoluta, para descarte dos dados basta [fechar a conexão](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), função que pode ser chamada a qualquer momento antes do fim do programa (é até muito comum considerando a natureza embarcada do sqlite).